# Adding Auto Scroll to this jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

Hello can anyone help?

I am using this full page slider..

http://www.musca.se/full-window-width-jquery-tools-content-slider-demo/

However i need to make it auto slide once the page loads, rather than just having the navigation.

This is the code that is used on the demo.

```
$(function() {
// Adds a class to the html code so we can target browsers without JS.
$('html').addClass('JS');
// Sets the slides width on page load
var i = $(window).width();
if (i > 904){ $('#items > li').css({ width: i }); }

// Scrollable and navigator plugin settings.
$("#slider").scrollable({ easing: 'easeOutQuad', speed: 904, circular: true }).navigator({ navi: '#navigation' });

// Window resize code
window.api = $("#slider").data("scrollable");
$(window).resize(function() {
    var a = 1 + window.api.getIndex();
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w > 904) {
        var l = a * w
        $('#items').css({ left: + - +l });
        $('#items > li').css({ width: w });
    } else {
        $('#items > li').css({ width: 904 });
    }
});
});
```

Apparently adding this to it will ensure it auto slider...

```
$("#slider").scrol​lable({ circular: true }).autoscroll({ autoplay: true, autopause: false, interval: 2000 })
```

But i cannot figure out where it goes. :(

Can anyone who knows about these things help me out?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to ready event:

```
setInterval(function(){
$('#navigation-wrapper span.next').click()
},1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i'm not sure where to put that?

The navigation is in #navigation-wrapper > ul#navigation > li etc etc

Comment: I am using this scrollable thing also but when It initiates it scroll all the logos at once.And then stops and then again begins with scrolling them one by one.I do not want the initial all logo scroll.Do we have any option for this?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$("#slider").scrollable({ easing: 'easeOutQuad', speed: 904, circular: true }).navigator({ navi: '#navigation' });
```

to

```
$("#slider").scrol​lable({ easing: 'easeOutQuad', speed: 904, circular: true }).navigator({ navi: '#navigation' }).autoscroll({ autoplay: true, autopause: false, interval: 2000 });
```

I know I am late to the party, but maybe someone else find it useful.